# Angular ng-repeat with constant & Restangular

Tags: angularjs, constants, angularjs-ng-repeat, restangular

I'm working with a weird data model (no way around it at this point). I'm using restangular to make a rest call to get back a single resource object

Normally, the resource object returned by restangular is just whatever I set my 
$scope.resource = response to and I can do resource.name , resource.id in the view/template, etc..

Except this group of resources instead of returning the key, value pairs in the response object, it returns an object within an object like so

```
resource1: {name: 'value', stuff: 'value', etc}
```

which is fine because then I would just set my $scope.resource = response.resource1 in my controller

except the problem is, is that there's 5 different kind of resource object names so if I make a resource by id call I might get back resource2, resource4, resource1, etc. so setting my $scope.resource = response.resource1 would only work when I get resource1.

My first attempt to solve this was to just use ng-repeat in which I set

```
<ul ng-repeat="(resource, value) in resource">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            Name:
            <span class="pull-right"> {{ resource.name }} </span>
        </li>
</ul>
```

which works great except because restangular returns all this extra stuff it's looping through each object it's repeating a bunch of blank html stuff if that makes sense.

My other thought was to try making a constant and make an object that has all 5 resources there and my ng-repeat would only populate based off that constant object (ie: it would check for those strings "resource1, resource2, etc" and if it's there then it will populate the template. But I'm not exactly sure how to do this.

Any other options or are there ng-repeat features i'm just not utilizing? any Help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/MjxzKQjd6atj3Vmj5tOy) I will be working from. Initially your incoming data looks something like this I believe...

```
 $scope.data = [
 {
   resource1 : { name: 'r1' }
 },
 {
   resource2 : { name: 'r2' }
 },
 {
   resource2 : { name: 'r2' }
 }];
```

When you receive the data you can normalize it by flattening it out into the following structure...

```
$scope.normalized = [
  { name : 'r1' },
  { name : 'r2' },
  { name : 'r2' }
];
```

Or you can add a common field for the object "type"

```
$scope.expanded = [
  {
    type : 'resource1',
    resource1 : { name: 'r1' }
  },
  {
    type : 'resource2',
    resource2 : { name: 'r2' }
  },
  {
    type : 'resource2',
    resource2 : { name: 'r2' }
  }];
```

Or you can normalize but retain type data...

```
$scope.normalizedType = [
  { type : 'resource1', name : 'r1' },
  { type : 'resource2', name : 'r2' },
  { type : 'resource2', name : 'r2' }
];
```

Normalizing upon retrieval of the data is probably your best bet. The question then becomes do you need to retain the objects type information.

Comment: Interesting approach, I like it. The answer to your question is that I don't. I just need to retain the resources key value pairs. The resource id is in the restangular response so if I need to do any POST's I can just grab it from there. Do you you think you can point me in the right direction for how to normalize it in my controller? I have about 15 different key value pairs with varying information in the single resource object I'm trying to display information from.

Comment: You can see all the properties for a given object using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). From there it's a matter of determining which properties to preserve and how to extract those properties in the most generic manner to minimize the number of tests and calls you make.

Comment: right, it's just turning into a cumbersome project. Ideally I would figure out a way to do all this in the view to get the right information. I'll dig deeper and see how I might be able to normalize this in my controller even though I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: The view is to display data, you should be doing little to no data manipulation there. Ideally you receive data in the correct format already, because that is not an option you should probably normalize your data upon retrieval to ensure consistency throughout your application.

Answer (score 0):

So another solution I came up with was put all the resource key names into a list

```
resources = ['resource1', 'resource2', 'resource3', 'etc..']
```

and in my restangular service promise I just checked for which resource number it would be with a for loop like this

```
return ResourceRestangular.all('resource').get(resourceId).then(function(response){
        for (i = 0; i < resources.length ; i++){
            if (resources[i] in response){
               self.resource = response[resources[i]];
            }
        }
            return self.resource;
```

No need for ng-repeat anymore!